# Windows Phone DateTime exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime

I'm currently working on localizing a Windows Phone application but I've started getting an index out of range exception on DateTime.Now.ToString().

I've tried changing the timezone of my computer but the error persists.

I'm unsure of what caused this problem or what to do to fix it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

---

STACK TRACE (added on request)

---

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.GetYearMonthPattern(int calID = 1) + 0x25 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InitializeOverridableProperties() + 0x94 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.Calendar.set(System.Globalization.Calendar value = {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar}) + 0x1a8 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.DateTimeFormatInfo(System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord cultureTable = {System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord}, System.Globalization.Calendar cal = {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar}) + 0x29 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.get() + 0x19 bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetFormat(System.Type formatType = {Name = "DateTimeFormatInfo" FullName = "System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo"}) + 0x22 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.get() + 0x2a bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.DateTime.ToString() 
>   QuickAirtime.dll!QuickAirtime.PaymentSummary.btnTransactionClick(object sender = {System.Windows.Controls.Button}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e = {System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs}) Line 78 + 0x2 bytes C#
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick() + 0x1f bytes 
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick() + 0x1f bytes    
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs}) + 0x4e bytes    
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Controls.Control ctrl = {System.Windows.Controls.Button}, System.EventArgs e = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs}) + 0xc bytes   
    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj = 227599168, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs = 227256368, int argsTypeIndex = 169, int actualArgsTypeIndex = 169, string eventName = "M@@4") + 0x115 bytes    
    [External Code]
```

Comment: Are you really sure the exception is thrown by DateTime.Now.ToString() ? That seems impossible. (please post the exception stack trace)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert I've edited the question to show the StackTrace

Comment: Can you show us the actual line of code that causes the exception (and a couple of lines around it) so we have a minimal example that reproduces the error? Also: are you forcing a culture that is not supported by the emulator/phone device?

Comment: Can you add the `btnTransactionClick()` code as well?

Comment: What is the current date and the culture of your computer? What is the value of DateTime.Now.Year? Does the issue occur on the emulator, on the device, or both?

Answer (score 1):

My app was localized and I did not use Culture Codes in the correct format, for example, I would use en instead of en-US or fr instead of fr-FR.

Once I became specific as explained above, the `DateTime.Now.ToString()` began to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the date is invalid for the current culture's calendar.

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx): *The ToString() method returns the string representation of the date and time in the calendar used by the current culture. If the value of the current DateTime instance is earlier than Calendar.MinSupportedDateTime or later than Calendar.MaxSupportedDateTime, the method throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException*.

What is the current culture in your app?

Comment: I'm using the default en culture, I didn't specify US or GB. Unsure as to whether the default switches to London or American time however. And in cases of localization, how do I ensure that the app culture choice doesn't clash with the phone culture? i.e. if that is what is happening at the moment.

Comment: So i'm confused however, what supplies the date to what in the case of my error? Is it app to phone emulator or phone emulator to app or app to system? Where exactly is the error from and what is complaining?